# OWASP ZAP Proxy freezes

Tags: java, owasp, zap

I recently started doing some exercises on [Hacking-Lab](http://www.hacking-lab.com).

In one task I wanted to do an "active scan" on a website. The scan run up to 100% fairly quickly, but then the ZAP tool was frozen. I could not click on anything but the close button. However, the tool still captures packets from the internet.

The guys from Hacking-Lab suggested to use a different JDK from Oracle instead of the OpenJDK they used. Unfortunately, this did not work.

Does someone has the same problem or a hint how to solve that problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, If I click a large size of JavaScript file (or a link) from the Alert tab then the application freezes instantly or moves slow. So, I did the following steps and it relieved the issue:

1. Double click an event that doesn't cause the issue from the History tab.
2. Right click in the response body area, go to Syntax, disable Auto Detect and set Plain. Then right click again, go to View, disable Word Wrap.
3. Navigate any JavaScript file from the Alert tab to see the difference.

If you want more help, try uploading an issue to the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues).

Answer (score 0):

yes try installing oracle JDK instead of Open JDK then switch between them as you need but check java version if switched or not ... this works for me.